# How to convert txt file to csv

Tags: conversion

I have a txt file from a agricultural machine. I need to convert this txt file to csv format. The txt file column names are separated by inverted commas and the values are separated by space. The values are included decimals and hyphens. I tried in excel but the result is not in the right format.

Comment: What about Excel didn't work? Did you try using Text To Columns?

Comment: Have you tried LibreOffice? I do this many times and works great. You can create a new spreadsheet document, copy the content of the file, which will trigger an assistant and then you can finally save it as CSV

Comment: No, I can not access LibreOffice from my machine. Is there any other options?

Comment: If you really cannot use Excel's Text to columns (to convert the data in excel, or while importing to excel) then I suggest [learning] e.g. Python (has nice features for text handling) or som other similar scripting means.

Comment: have you tried opening it in notepad (or notepad++, or sed) and replace all (space to comma)?

Comment: https://convertio.co/txt-csv/